# Measurable sets and arithmetic progressions

Tags: lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

Let $A$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set with positive measure.Prove that $\forall$ $n$$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, $A$ contains an arithmetic progression of length $n$.
Can somenone help me with this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am new to this site.i did not know how to do that.

Comment: thank you for your comment.

Comment: No problem! This is just for your information. If you don't know how to do it, you can tell me. You just have to click on the check mark ✓ next to the answers, so that the question is _solved_.

Comment: Oh yes  you are right.Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544763